# Android Touch UP not working

Tags: java, android, android-event

im kinda stuck with this project in android im trying to figure out why this is not working but i have no idea.This is By the way a custom view just in case.

The problem is this the event ACTION_DOWN is working perfectly im getting the console debug  "Touching 1" and "Touching 2" but ACTION_UP,ACTION_CANCEL or default: are not working i cant figure this out so any help would be really appreciated thank you

```
        public void doTouch(MotionEvent event)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch(action)
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(x < 125 && y < 125){
                    for(AnimatedSprite a:mSprites)
                    {
                        if(a.getID() == 1)
                        {
                            a.AdvanceToFrame(0);
                            touching = true;
                            System.out.println("Touching 1");
                            //touch_obj1 = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(x > getWidth()-125 && y > getHeight()-125)
                {
                    for(AnimatedSprite a:mSprites)
                    {
                        if(a.getID() == 2)
                        {
                            a.AdvanceToFrame(1);
                            System.out.println("Touching 2");
                            touching = true;
                            //touch_obj2 = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    touching = false;
                }
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    System.out.println("Touch UP");
                    touching = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("NOT Touching");
                    touching = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

here is where im calling the doTouch function

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            thread.doTouch(event);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling your `doTouch` method?  Specifically, I'm wondering whether you are returning true from the `onTouchEvent()` call.

Comment: well i can but as i said the ACTION_DOWN is being detected but let me modify the question so i can show you the code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like your problem is the way you are handling touch events in `onTouchEvent`.  You need to return true from `onTouchEvent` if you want to handle touch events.  So, if you get an `ACTION_DOWN` and return false from `onTouchEvent` the system will not send you any more touch events related until the next `ACTION_DOWN` event.

Without knowing exactly what you are doing with the touch events, I can't give you a solution that will definitely work for your situation, but if you want to receive any touch events other than `ACTION_DOWN` you will need to return true from `onTouchEvent`.

Comment: Sorry i took this long to answer but while it does sound logic, like i said actiondown works perfectly just action up is not working it would be strange for them not to return true i guess but maybe im wrong

Comment: yes, as I mentioned in my answer, you will _always_ get `ACTION_DOWN` but you will not get the other events unless you return true from `onTouchEvent` in response to the `ACTION_DOWN` event.

Comment: ok thank you since this makes sense im making it the right answer

Answer (score 0):

ok i got this fixed what i had to do was this

1)i changed the function so it could return a

```
boolean public bool doTouch(MotionEvent event)
```

2)of course i returned true at the end of that function

3)when calling it i did this

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return doTouch(event);
    }
```