# detect if the touch stopped on an android device screen

Tags: android, motion-detection, motionevent

I want to fire a method after a touch has been initiated and left the screen. I can detect the beginning of a touch by setting a OnTouch event to the View but can't detect when the hand leave the screen. I want to detect when does the touch stops. How can i detect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html - Specifically the use of `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. There is a lot of information on the link I've provided :)

> A gesture starts with a motion event with ACTION_DOWN that provides the location of the first pointer down. As each additional pointer that goes down or up, the framework will generate a motion event with ACTION_POINTER_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_UP accordingly. Pointer movements are described by motion events with ACTION_MOVE. Finally, a gesture end either when the final pointer goes up as represented by a motion event with ACTION_UP or when gesture is canceled with ACTION_CANCEL.

Comment: Thanks a lot.it seemed i misunderstood a lot. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to detect touch up.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641064/android-touch-up-not-working).  Basically it says that you need to return true to process anything other than ACTION_DOWN.